# Is it possible to set user/group/table level Hive configuration parameters?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I would like to set (enforce) certain Hive parameters for some users or user groups. Case in point, I would like to set `hive.mapred.mode = strict`, and enforce this for all "new" users who might be prone to writing poorly constructed Hive queries. This way I wont have such users doing full scans unnecessarily on very large tables with perfectly well defined partitions.

I don't necessarily want this to be set at the entire cluster level, as it might be too restrictive for all users, especially power users who know what they are doing. I also cannot rely on these users setting this themselves at a session level either.

So what options do I have to achieve this?

Comment: Create an alias in the user's `.bash_profile` like `hive='hive --hiveconf hive.mapred.mode = strict'`

Comment: That would work from edge nodes. But if users use the HUE interface, it won't.

Comment: Technically you should provide only `impala` as a querying interface in `hue`. Your _not-so-technical_ guys will only be performing `select`s, I guess and it's faster.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not a valid blanket statement. There are many reasons we cannot have everything come through impala. Issues are a combination of UDFs and user security (best left for a different discussion)

Comment: Actually, @philantrovert, instead of .bash_profile, the same solution would probably be better suited for using .hiverc file instead. I wish that extended to HUE.

Answer (score 0):

You can make hive.mapred.mode = strict for all your users.

The users who know what they are doing will change this to hive.mapred.mode = nonstrict before running their query. They will be able to do this by running both the statements in the same session.

Comment: Lol, simple! :). Although I am not sure where all existing code would need to change. Any way to have this affect only the new group and not cause regression issues everywhere else?